# How to add columns with a for loop in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes df1, df2 described below

df1

```
         prod  age
0  Winalto_eu   28
1  Winalto_uc   25
2      CEM_eu   30
```

df2

```
    age   qx
0    25  2.7
1    26  2.8
2    27  2.8
3    28  2.9
4    29  3.0
5    30  3.2
6    31  3.4
7    32  3.7
8    33  4.1
9    34  4.6
10   35  5.1
11   36  5.6
12   37  6.1
13   38  6.7
14   39  7.5
15   40  8.2
```

I would like to add new columns with a for loop to df1. 
The names of the new colums should be qx1, qx2,...qx10

```
for i in range(0,10):
    df1['qx'+str(i)]
```

The values of qx1 should be affected by the loop, doing a kind of vlookup on the age : 
For instance on the first row, for the prod 'Winalto_eu', the value of qx1 should be the value of 
df2['qx'] at the age of 28+1, qx2 the same at 28+2...

The target dataframe should look like this :

```
         prod  age  qx1  qx2  qx3  qx4  qx5  qx6  qx7  qx8  qx9  qx10
0  Winalto_eu   28  3.0  3.2  3.4  3.7  4.1  4.6  5.1  5.6  6.1   6.7
1  Winalto_uc   25  2.8  2.8  2.9  3.0  3.2  3.4  3.7  4.1  4.6   5.1
2      CEM_eu   30  3.4  3.7  4.1  4.6  5.1  5.6  6.1  6.7  7.5   8.2
```

Have you any idea ? 
Thanks

Comment: This consists of basic techniques: (1) identify the starting cell in `df2` based on the age from `df1`; (2) extract a 10-cell slice of column `qx` in `df2`; (3) add the column slice to augment each row in `df`. (4) Finally, you likely want to vectorize that sequence, rather than doing a loop.

Comment: Each of these is readily available by browser search.  We usually like to see your attempt before we help you.  Stack Overflow is more to repair and augment existing code, rather than to write a difficult sequence from scratch.  If nothing else, create the new black columns and start filling in values.  Post an update if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would give what you want. I used shift function to first generate additional columns in df2 and then merged with df1.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'prod': ['Winalto_eu', 'Winalto_uc', 'CEM_eu'], 'age' : [28, 25, 30]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'age': list(range(25,41)), 'qx': [2.7, 2.8, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 3.2, 3.4, 3.7, 4.1, 4.6, 5.1, 5.6, 6.1, 6.7, 7.5, 8.2]})

for i in range(1,11):
    df2['qx'+str(i)] = df2.qx.shift(-i)

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how = 'left',on = ['age'])
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning you should try with pd.df.set_index('prod",inplace=True) after that transponse df with qx

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using `.loc` filtering the data:

```
top_n = 10

values = [df2.loc[df2['age'].gt(x),'qx'].iloc[:top_n].tolist() for x in df1['age']]

coln = ['qx'+str(x) for x in range(1,11)]

df1[coln] = pd.DataFrame(values)

         prod  age  qx1  qx2  qx3  qx4  qx5  qx6  qx7  qx8  qx9  qx10
0  Winalto_eu   28  3.0  3.2  3.4  3.7  4.1  4.6  5.1  5.6  6.1   6.7
1  Winalto_uc   25  2.8  2.8  2.9  3.0  3.2  3.4  3.7  4.1  4.6   5.1
2      CEM_eu   30  3.4  3.7  4.1  4.6  5.1  5.6  6.1  6.7  7.5   8.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Ridiculously overengineered solution:

```
pd.concat([df1,pd.DataFrame(columns=['qx'+str(i) for i in range(11)], 
                            data=[ser1.T.loc[:,i:i+10].values.flatten().tolist()
                                  for i in df1['age']])],
          axis=1)

    prod    age qx0 qx1 qx2 qx3 qx4 qx5 qx6 qx7 qx8 qx9 qx10
0   Winalto_eu  28  2.9 3.0 3.2 3.4 3.7 4.1 4.6 5.1 5.6 6.1 6.7
1   Winalto_uc  25  2.7 2.8 2.8 2.9 3.0 3.2 3.4 3.7 4.1 4.6 5.1
2   CEM_eu  30  3.2 3.4 3.7 4.1 4.6 5.1 5.6 6.1 6.7 7.5 8.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df=df1.assign(key=0).merge(df2.assign(key=0), on="key", suffixes=["", "_y"]).query("age<age_y").drop(["key"], axis=1)

df["q"]=df.groupby("prod")["age_y"].rank()

#to keep only 10 positions for each
df=df.loc[df["q"]<=10]

df=df.pivot_table(index=["prod", "age"], columns="q", values="qx")

df.columns=[f"qx{col:0.0f}" for col in df.columns]

df=df.reset_index()
```

Output:

```py
         prod  age  qx1  qx2  qx3  ...  qx6  qx7  qx8  qx9  qx10
0      CEM_eu   30  3.4  3.7  4.1  ...  5.6  6.1  6.7  7.5   8.2
1  Winalto_eu   28  3.0  3.2  3.4  ...  4.6  5.1  5.6  6.1   6.7
2  Winalto_uc   25  2.8  2.8  2.9  ...  3.4  3.7  4.1  4.6   5.1
```